# Accessing the length of QueryList inside an Angular2 template

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have an Angular template that gets children passed to it using:

```
@ContentChildren(Item) QueryList<Item> items;
```

Inside the template, these items are placed in a table, firstly used in the table head to display headers:

```
        <table class="table nomargin table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let item of items" ngClass="{{item.classes}}">
```

... which works as expected. While the content is loading, I have a loading gif that spans all the columns displaying a loading gif, I want this loading gif to span the number of columns specified in `items`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngIf="display.loading">
                <td class="text-center ajax-loader" [attr.colspan]="{{items?.toArray().length}}" >
                    <br />
                    <img src="../img/ajax-loader-4.gif"/>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    Loading ...
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and it's failing with:

> An error occurred loading file:
>   package:______/components/table-component.ngfactory.dart

As soon as I remove `[attr.colspan]="{{items?.toArray().length}}"`, the error goes away again. Same error for `[attr.colspan]="{{items?.length}}"`.

`items` does have a `length` property so `toArray` is probably not needed.

In the pub output I'm seeing:

> [web] GET
>   packages/______/components/table-component.ngfactory.dart →
>   Could not find asset
>   ______|lib/components/table-component.ngfactory.dart.

If I just do `colspan="{{items?.length}}"` it just gets ignored.

Am I missing some directive? This is what I currently have:

```
@View(
    directives: const [NgFor, NgIf, NgClass],
```

What is the right way to make use of the length of `items` in an attribute in an angular2 template?

Comment: Did you check `Item` component instances are actually instantiated for `*ngFor="let item of items"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@View()**

`@View()` annotation was removed in beta.11 already. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-2016-03-18

Just move the parameters to `@Component(...)` instead.

**PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES**

If you add

```
  transformers:
  - angular2/transform/codegen:
      platform_directives: 'package:angular2/src/common/directives.dart#CORE_DIRECTIVES'
```

to your `pubspec.yaml` then you don't need to add these directives explicitely

```
@View(
    directives: const [NgFor, NgIf, NgClass],`
```

**[] and {{}}**

`[attr.colspan]="{{items?.length}}"`
`[]` is for object binding, `{{}}` is for string binding. Both together is invalid.

Supported is either

```
[attr.colspan]="items?.length"
```

or

```
attr.colspan="{{items?.length}}"
```

while the 2nd assigns the result of `items?.length.toString()`

Comment: This seems to fix it:
`[attr.colspan]="items?.length"`

Thanks for the transformer advice!

Comment: Should I log a bug for the `{{}}` failing? without it works 100%

Comment: See my updated answer. That's not supposed to work. See also https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/ff20b559755675544cb3a97c173c98697bf9ae80/public/docs/_examples/dependency-injection/dart/pubspec.yaml for how to make pipes available globally. You can also add your own directives and pipes this way to make them available globally